# Certreq New INF File

Tags: iis, iis-7, certificate, certreq

I want to creat a Certificate Request with the Certreq.exe Command.
To start a new request I need the mandatory inf file.

There is my problem, I need a inf file which creates, except the normal Variables (CN, O, OU, Provider, length ...) exact the same as if I would create the Cert Crequest over the IIS GUI.

My Question therefor, is there a way to find out what the "standard" key arguments that MS uses are or can I get this from an already create certificate (I know the Cert Details, there arent all infos need)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get information about existing IIS SSL certificate you can do that by using command

```
certutil -v -store my
```

This will show (probably all) information that you need to make inf file for `certreq` like Subject, SubjectAlternativeName, extensions, exportable flag and CSP name.

Inf file would then look like (taken from [here](http://www.entrust.net/knowledge-base/technote.cfm?tn=8649))

```
[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"

[NewRequest]
;Change to your,country code, company name and common name
Subject = "C=US, O=Example Co, CN=something.example.com"

KeySpec = 1
KeyLength = 2048
Exportable = TRUE
MachineKeySet = TRUE
SMIME = False
PrivateKeyArchive = FALSE
UserProtected = FALSE
UseExistingKeySet = FALSE
ProviderName = "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider"
ProviderType = 12
RequestType = PKCS10
KeyUsage = 0xa0

[EnhancedKeyUsageExtension]
OID=1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 ; this is for Server Authentication / Token Signing
```

To generate the request you would then run command

```
certreq -new request.inf request.csr
```

and send `request.csr` to a CA to issuing a certificate. CA may use all information in your certificate request but does not have to, i.e. it might change extensions like enhanced key usage and add bot `Client Authentication` and `Server Authentication`.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I were looking for.

Comment: The above is correct, you can also add in a FriendlyName = "Use for Cert", the key length of 2048 is weak these days, this can be 4096, 8192 or 16384 and the Extended Key Usage OID for client auth is OID=1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2; Client Authentication, same as above for server authentication token signing.